# Button in Navigation Bar in Tab Bar UIViewController not showing

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I can't seem to get any buttons to appear in my navigation bar.

Flow:  Navigation Controller -> Tab bar Controller -> ViewController (want to put button here)

I've tried adding it programmatically inside of ViewDidLoad:

```
let navigationBar = navigationController!.navigationBar
    navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()

let leftButton =  UIBarButtonItem(title: "Left Button", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: nil)
let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Right Button", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: nil)

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton
```

I've also tried adding it using the storyboard but it doesnt show during runtime.  Any idea why I can't get a button to appear in the navigation bar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it like this instead:

```
self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [leftButton]
```

Comment: inside of ViewDidLoad

Comment: still doesn't work.  It's frustrating because I'm able to add button's onto the navigation bar of other viewcontrollers that don't have tabs on the bottom.  I don't know why viewcontrollers with tabs are giving me a problem

Comment: How are you segueing to your UITabBarController from your UINavigationController?

Answer (score -2):

views from storyboard or xib load after viewWillAppear method call. and viewDidLoad method call before viewWillAppear.

so navigation bar is nil during viewDidLoad method so they are not appear.so **write you code in viewdidappear** method and your buttons will be appeared.

Comment: I've added it inside of ViewDidAppear and it didn't work.  The issue appears to only occur on viewcontrollers with tabs on the bottom from the tabcontroller

Comment: can you give me dome code? i will try to resolve your problem.